# Error creating new disk on Azure from snapshot

Tags: azure, powershell

I am want to create a new disk from an image called "python3" on Azure to use in a VM scale set. Here is the relevant code:

```
$BaseDiskName = "python3_disk_20210614"
$SnapshotName = "python3"

$snapshot = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -SnapshotName $SnapshotName
$diskconfig = New-AzDiskConfig -Location $LocationName -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -CreateOption Copy
$newdisk = New-AzDisk $diskconfig -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DiskName $BaseDiskName
```

When display the properties of $diskconfig, this is what I get:

```
ResourceGroupName            :
ManagedBy                    :
ManagedByExtended            :
Sku                          :
Zones                        :
TimeCreated                  :
OsType                       :
HyperVGeneration             :
CreationData                 : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.CreationData
DiskSizeGB                   :
DiskSizeBytes                :
UniqueId                     :
EncryptionSettingsCollection :
ProvisioningState            :
DiskIOPSReadWrite            :
DiskMBpsReadWrite            :
DiskIOPSReadOnly             :
DiskMBpsReadOnly             :
DiskState                    :
Encryption                   :
MaxShares                    :
ShareInfo                    :
Id                           :
Name                         :
Type                         :
Location                     : Central US
Tags                         :
NetworkAccessPolicy          :
DiskAccessId                 :
Tier                         :
BurstingEnabled              :
```

When running the last line of script, I get the following error:

*New-AzDisk : Resource python3 is not found.
ErrorCode: NotFound
ErrorMessage: Resource python3 is not found.
ErrorTarget:
StatusCode: 404
ReasonPhrase: Not Found
OperationID : 37907fcd-b55b-4851-9c7e-43fdb187bbfe
At V:\Modeling Software\computing\working\launch_VM - Copy.ps1:34 char:12

- $newdisk = New-AzDisk $diskconfig -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupNa
- ```
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzDisk], ComputeCloudException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.NewAzureRmDisk*

However, I can read and view the $diskconfig object which was loaded from the python3 image. How can python3 be not found when it was just used in the line above?

Comment: Could you please add `-debug` in your command to get error in detail?

Comment: You didn't specify the `-Disk` parameter before parsing `$diskconfig`.  `$newdisk = New-AzDisk -Disk $diskconfig -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DiskName $BaseDiskName`

Comment: Were you able to get it fixed with the above or it's still giving you the same error?

Comment: Ked Mardemootoo's suggesting fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ok great, I've replied with this as the answer, please help to mark it accordingly so as to close this question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you were missing the parameter `-Disk` right before parsing the variable `$diskconfig` in your command. It should just be changed to:

```
$newdisk = New-AzDisk -Disk $diskconfig -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DiskName $BaseDiskName
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/new-azdisk?view=azps-6.0.0) a reference to the Azure Documentation for the `New-AzDisk` cmdlet.